# How to know if event group {task} is enabled or disabled in Celery

Tags: python, celery

In celery, we can enable or disable task event by:

```
celery control -A proj enable_events
```

or

```
celery control -A proj enable_events
```

When running this command from, it says - `task events already enabled` or `task events enabled`

This indicates that there's status for task - event enabled or disabled. I was wondering how to get is programmatically.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the code as the following shown

```
app = Celery()
app.config_from_object('conf.config')

response = app.control.enable_events(reply=True)
# print response here
```

Comment: that doesn't returns the status whether event is already enabled or disabled.

Comment: You could get the result by setting **reply=True** when calling enable_events()